# Post request in custom autorisation form return 403

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Try to create custom *AuthenticationProvider*. Right now just add println for check use Spring this class or not. And right there starting something strange:

Take example from official documentation:

```
http
.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated() 
    .and()
.formLogin()                      
    .and()
.httpBasic();
```

Spring execute my custom *AuthenticationProvider*. Then take example for custom login page:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll();
```

View:

```
form.ui.form(action="/login", method="post")
            h4.ui.dividing.header Autorisation
            .field
                label Login
                input(name="username" placeholder="Логин" type="text")
            .field
                label Пароль
                input(name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password")
            button.ui.button(type="submit") Submit
```

Page will open, but if we try to press `submit`, it will return 403. Сustom *AuthenticationProvider* doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security default csrf option is enabled. And if you post without csrf token, Spring Security produces 403 forbidden error.

```
http
.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
.csrf()
    .disabled();
```

or append csrf token in your form.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure